# Android - Using databinding to assign a layout?

Tags: android, xml, button

I'm trying to use data binding to assign a 'layout' attribute within an  tag. I'm passing in a boolean value that tells me if the app is in dark mode. I use this variable to determine if I should assign a white button layout or a black button layout.

I've tried to just do this intuitively since I've seen people use data binding booleans all the time to assign values in xml.

```
<include
      android:id="@+id/buy_with_google"
      layout="@{ isDarkMode ? @layout/buy_with_googlepay_button_white : @layout/buy_with_googlepay_button_black}"
```

> Error: ****/ data binding error ****msg:included value (@{ isDarkMode ? @layout/buy_with_googlepay_button_white : @layout/buy_with_googlepay_button_black}) must start with @layout/. file:[Redacted File Path] ****\ data binding error ****```

Does databinding just not work in a way that allows me to use logic to assign whole layouts like that?

Comment: Kindly check android data binding document for correct expressions https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions

Comment: I'm not sure if you misunderstood the question or not. The only expression I'm using is the ternary operator which is completely valid and I've seen used in a lot of places. Does it not work for a layout in an include tag?

Comment: As per my knowlwge I dont think it will work with layout attribute. Although check this article may be it will helps you https://medium.com/@elia.maracani/android-data-binding-passing-a-variable-to-an-include-d-layout-3567099b58f

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I'd love to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the include is executed at compile time and doesn't know about your `viewModel` or any runtime parameters.